# Does this measure make it such that $x^3 \ge 1$ almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$x^3 \ge 1$ almost everywhere

$\Longleftrightarrow \mu(\{x : x^3 < 1\}) = 0$

$\Longleftrightarrow \mu((-\infty, 1)) = 0$

Let $$\tau(E) = \int_Efdm$$

with $f = \chi_{(2, 3)}$

So $f$ is a non-negative measurable simple function and hence $\tau(E)$ is a measure.

Now we have,
$$\tau((-\infty, 1)) = \int_{(-\infty, 1)}\chi_{(2, 3)}dm$$

$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{(-\infty, 1)}\chi_{(2, 3)}dm$$

$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{(-\infty, 1) \cap (2, 3)}dm$$

$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{\{\emptyset\}}dm$$

$$= 1 \cdot m(\{\emptyset\})$$

$$= 1 \cdot 0 = 0$$

So does that look alright?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Do you mean  $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\tau$ plays the role of $\mu$ as a concrete instance?

Comment: @Berci Yes $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and it's being used in as part of 'new' measure $\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\tau(E)=m(E\cap(2,3))$, so that $\tau((-\infty,1))=0$ follows, in accordance with your calculations.

Comment: I actually something like that line in my workings, I'll edit it in now.